# How to get lines after match using grep for command line output?

Tags: grep

Trying to trim the output of a command on terminal. I want to see only strings after `blah` in a command line output. I tried

```
<command> | grep -A "blah"
```

but getting an error output as

> grep: illegal option -- A

Comment: `-A` is a GNU grep specific option. Which one are you using? Can you echo the output of `grep --version`?

Comment: `grep -A 10 "blah" file` = *"10 lines after"*

Comment: grep --version also says "grep: illegal option -- version
Usage: grep [-c|-l|-q] -bhinsvw pattern file . . ."

Comment: to do something like " grep -A 10 "blah" file " I'm not reading any file but the console output

Comment: can you add the sample input and the expected output to clear your requirements.. `-A 5` option is used for retrieving _5 lines after_ the grepped string

Comment: I'm running prtdiag -v command in solaris machine and I want only the data that come after "FW Version" in the terminal..

Answer (score 0):

I am using cut in-conjunction with grep to get strings after a keyword "blah" in this case

```
echo "random text string blah strings  after" | grep -o  "blah.*$" | cut -c 5-
```

grep portion of command extracts whole line after "blah" including "blah" and cut command removes first 4 characters from this string. Only first occurrence of "blah" will be used as delimiter to trim the line.

Comment: I'm grepping from terminal output and the .*$ at the end did not help me to get lines after the given string but only the line that is having the string.I don't have any problem if output contains the word I used to search but I want all the LINES after the word used to search was found.

Comment: file contains the text
line_num=`grep -nm1 "blah" file| cut -d ":" -f1` && sed -n "$line_num , $ p" file